# Multer is grabbing images but it is not saving my files in the correct directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have an express server. When the user goes to make a post request for the profiel. They submit a profile picture. I am trying to use multer to grab that photo/image that is being sent and store it in a folder on the backend directory.

I setup multer but for some reason it is not saving any of the photos that I want it to save locally so that I can retrieve it. How can I fix this issue. Does anyone have an idea on how to go about this.

controller:

```
const Profile = require("../../models/UserModels/Profiles.js")
const User = require('../../models/UserModels/Users.js')

const multer = require('multer')
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '../../client/images/profile/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)
  }
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
...
  post:(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.files)
    upload.single(req.files.profile_pic.name) <----------------
    let body = req.body
    Profile.create({
      profile_pic: req.files.profile_pic.name,
      f_name: body.f_name,
      l_name: body.l_name,
      bio: body.bio,
      location: body.location,
      sm_facebook: body.sm_facebook,
      sm_instagram: body.sm_instagram,
      sm_twitter: body.sm_twitter,
      sm_website: body.sm_website,
      followers: body.followers,
      following: body.following,
      photos: body.photos,
      downloads: body.downloads,
      edits: body.edits,
      userId: body.userId
    })
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data).status(200)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
      res.send(err).status(400)
    })
  },
```

Here is the direcory for this backend:
[image]

-----------update---------------

this is the react axios request from the frontend:

```
function createProfile(userId){
    let data = new FormData()
    data.append('f_name', firstName)
    data.append('l_name', lastName)
    data.append('bio', bio)
    data.append('location', location)
    data.append('sm_facebook', facebook)
    data.append('sm_instagram', instagram)
    data.append('sm_twitter', twitter)
    data.append('sm_website', website)
    data.append('followers', 0)
    data.append('following', 0)
    data.append('photos', 0)
    data.append('edits', 0)
    data.append('downloads', 0)
    data.append('userId', userId)
    data.append('profile_pic', profilePicture)
    console.log(data)
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/api/profile/",
      data: data,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return(<Navigate to='/' />)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Ok, based on the axios example you provided, you'll end up with `router('base/route').post('example', upload.single('profile_pic'), (req, res) => { .. })`. In this example the `base/route` is the main route of your `express` router and the `example` is the specific route of your controller. As I told you before, `upload.single()` should be used as a middleware and in your case, it should match the example I've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the storage path for multer as if you were located on the root folder of the project.
So instead of using `'../../client/images/profile/'` as storage path, you should use: `'./backend/client/images/profile'`.

You'll code should end up as follows:

```
const multer = require('multer')
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './backend/client/images/profile')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Quick question, when I call upload, do I have to pass in the image name or the image object. I tried both and it did not end up storing it in the profile directory.

Comment: Also, I am calling upload, but it looks like nothing is being called. I added a ```console.log()``` in the ```filename:``` and it is not being shown which leads me to believe it is not being called. Do you know why this would be happening

Comment: You should use the `upload.single()` function as a middleware. Also, `single()` takes the name of the field on which you are providing the file. E.G: If the name of the field that contains the photo is 'picture' you'll end up with something like `upload.single('picture')`.
Then on the actual controller, you'll have access to the `file` property on your `req` object (`req.file`); it will contain the information of the provided file.

Comment: I tried it will the file name but it did not do anything. WHen you say ```upload.single()``` as middleware. should it not be in the controller. If it does not belong in the controller, where should i call ```upload.single()```.  I feel like I am close to getting it but it is not saving..

Comment: You should pass `upload.single()` right after the route of your controller (again, it's a middleware). E.G: `.post('example', upload.single('field_name_on_the_form_data'), (req, res) => { .. })`

Also, the name you should pass to `upload.single()` is **the name of the field that contains the file**. If you provided the file in a `form data` and the field that contains the file is named `file` or `image` that's what you will pass as a parameter to `upload.single()` you'll end up with: `upload.single('file')`, for example.

Comment: So it does not matter that The frontend is react and that the file is sent to the backend through an axios request with the file in it. I will update the original post with the axios request that I am making to the backend with the file in it.